# problema con un link de un archivo

Tags: php, html5

Estoy creando una pagina y todo me funcionaba bien pero un archivo que antes era html le cambie la terminación a un archivo .php pero cuando presiono el link no me manda a ese archivo ósea a categoria.php me envía al archivo pero con el nombre que tenia antes ósea categoria.html
Además también cuando modifico algo dentro del archivo donde esta el link los cambios no se muestran en la pagina esta como si no hubiese cambiado nada.
Espero puedan ayudarme, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

La página en la que tienes el enlace a categoria.php es un archivo .html?
Seguramente el navegador tenga en caché la versión anterior del archivo y por eso te está mostrando la versión que tiene guardada.

Para que te muestre la versión actualizada tienes que limpiar el cache del navegador.

En la mayoría de navegadores, pulsando al mismo tiempo "shift + ctrl + delete" deberia llevarte a la ventana de configuración desde la que puedes borrar la cache.

También puedes pulsar ctrl + f5 o shift + ctrl + R para recargar la página borrando el caché de la misma.

En MacOS puedes recargar la pagina borrando el cache con Cmd + Shift + Delete

Comment: ok, gracias lo intentare